# Ubuntu 18.04 Preseed error message when kernel option keymap=uk is used

Tags: system-installation, kernel, keyboard, keyboard-layout

If I add the kernel boot option `keymap=uk`, the preseed does not ask about the keyboard used which is what I want.

Unfortunately, later in the package install, I get an error message:

```
Debootstrap warning : Failure to configure base packages
```

If I remove the `keymap=uk` kernel option, I don't get this error message and everything gets installed correctly, but I always get asked about the keyboard used questions, which I don't want.

Any idea about the way to suppress the keyboard type questions, but still allow the preseed install to complete ?